Getting height of dynamically added HTML element
I retrieve HTML text from a database and I am performing some animation to display the content. In order to keep layout clean I want to get the height and width of the element and empty it before starting my animation. But the onMount call does give me dimensions like it is empty.
I get the correct dimensions if the text is static but not dynamic. Is there anything I can do to avoid this ?
//+page.svelte
<script>
  import { page } from '$app/state';
</script>
<div class="catch-phrase">
    <TypewriterEffect>
        <div>
            { page.data.personalMessage}
        </div>
    </TypewriterEffect>
</div>
<style>
    .catch-phrase {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 10vw;
        max-width: 1200px;
        height: 90dvh;
    }
</style>

//Typewriter.svelte
<script>
    onMount(() => {
        fullNode = container.cloneNode(true);
        container.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';
        container.style.width = container.offsetWidth + 'px';
        container.innerHTML = '';
        isReady = true;
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            (entries) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                        console.log('launch !!');
                        typewriter();
                        observer.disconnect();
                    }
                });
            },
            {
                root: null, // viewport
                threshold: 1 // percentage of element visible
            }
        );
        observer.observe(container);
    });
    const typewriter = async () => {
        var fullHtmlText = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < fullNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if (fullNode.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1) {
                fullHtmlText = fullNode.childNodes[i].textContent;
                splittedText = splitHtmlText(fullHtmlText, chunkSize);
                container.appendChild(fullNode.childNodes[i]);
                container.childNodes[i].textContent = '';
                await type(container.childNodes[i], fullHtmlText, 0);
            }
        }

        function type(node, fullHtmlText, currentIndex) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (node.textContent.length >= fullHtmlText.length) {
                    resolve();
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    callback();
                    return;
                }
                node.innerHTML = splittedText.slice(0, currentIndex).join('');
                var timeout = setTimeout(() => type(node, fullHtmlText, currentIndex + 1), 10);
            });
        }
        return {
            destroy() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        };
    };
}
</script>
<div bind:this={container}>{@render children?.()}</div>

Here is a screenshot of the conatainer height :
Thanks for your help.

Apparently the problem comes from the page.data and seems to be a bug (posted here and here.
Using data.personalMessage message instead of page.data.personalMessage is both a workaround and a better practice.
//+page.svelte
<script>
   const { data } = $props();
</script>
<TypewriterEffect>
   {@html data.personalMessage}
</TypewriterEffect>

Thanks to @brunnerh for the solution.

The clone will not be in the document, so it cannot be measured.
I do not really see a reason to clone here, just take the measurements you need and store them in variables (if you need them again later).
The main issue in terms of layout should be that you are using a span which is an inline element, to change its size, you need to adjust the display property as well, e.g.
container.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';
container.style.width = container.offsetWidth + 'px';
container.style.display = 'inline-block';

(Or since that is not dynamic, move it to the <style>)
Also note that <span> elements have a very limited set of elements they are allowed to contain, so if you intend to add arbitrary HTML elements, it should be replaced with a <div> instead. <div> elements use display: block by default, which covers the full width by default.

I need to clone to keep a reference of the content and empty it so I can show it progressively (like a typewriter effect). My main problem is on the height dimension. I can see the difference because I vertically center the content with flex,  and when the content is static it show at the middle, and when it's not it starts from the middle and goes down. The code is a bit heavy so I'll try to show more while narrow it down.

You also can store the innerHTML in a variable.

If I store in a variable I lose the childNodes feature which I need to perform my animation. I added a more comprehensive part of my code.

As noted, that is already invalid, since you put a div into a span.

Also, the destroy logic would only be used if you were to use typewriter as an action via use:typewriter (and only if the function is not async).

Changed span to a div and I still have the issue. I'll look into your last comment thx.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I suspect it's the flex container and it's limited height. Try removing that.

If I remove the height:90dvh then catch-phrase takes the height of the Typewriter element which I set at container.style.height = container.offsetHeight + 'px';. Its value is 38px when I use page.data but the exact same content added statically shows a value of 580px and is therefore correctly centered. I thought there could be something with the fact that the data comes from the page.data rune but  I'll keep digging...
